Using FormSet to editing a array of same form in django
My requirement here is to enable user to add description and remark against multiple files uploaded earlier.I am using formset to display a set of partial field data of a model 'medical_doc'. I am new to django and am not able to implement it properly.
form.py
class Files_uploadedForm(forms.Form)
    doc_name=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    doc_type=forms.CharField(max_length=5)
    description=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    remarks=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
Files_uploadedFormSet=formset_factory(Files_uploadedForm)

view.py
if request.method='POST'
    med_qrset=medical_doc.objects.values('doc_name','doc_type','description','remarks') .filter(doc_id=doc_id)
    formset=Files_uploadedFormSet(queryset=med_qrset)
context = {'formset'=formset}
return render(request,"upload_doc.html")

upload_doc.html
...
{% for form in formset %}
form.as_p
{% endfor %}

Please excuse the syntax errors. My issue here is to know if this method of initialising formset is correct. Because I get a error saying that BaseFormSet.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'. Please help.
